# Feed CSV file into variable in Bash for parsing

Tags: bash, csv, scripting

For each row in a CSV file, I'd like to extract a field and reposition it in the row using Bash. The row is a URL and I am using `/` as a delimiter.

This is the starting file (start.csv):

```
https://docs.website.com/12-3/articles/guide-1/article-1.html
https://docs.website.com/12-2/articles/guide-2/article-5.html
https://docs.website.com/12-1/articles/guide-3/article-6.html
```

For later reference, the URL is `https://{url}/{version}/irrelevant/{guide}/irrelevant.html`.

The desired output is (end.csv):

```
url,name,tag,version,guide,views
https://docs.website.com/12-3/articles/guide-1/article-1.html,,,12-3,guide-1,0
https://docs.website.com/12-2/articles/guide-2/article-5.html,,,12-2,guide-2,0
https://docs.website.com/12-1/articles/guide-3/article-6.html,,,12-1,guide-3,0
```

I've unsuccessfully tried many variations of:

```
file="start.csv"
var="$(<<<"${file}" cut -d'/' -f4)"

sed -e "s|$|,$var,,,,0|g" < start.csv > end.csv
```

However this successfully produces a column with the version:

```
cut -d'/' -f4 < start.csv
```

Somewhere my logic is seriously flawed. Is anyone able to help me spot my problem? Thank you.

Comment: There are two problems here, one trivial, one serious. The trivial one is that `<<<"${file}" cut -d'/' -f4` passes the string "start.csv" as input to `cut`, rather than reading from the file by that name. The serious one is that (if you fix the first one) `$var` will contain the version for *all* lines (separated by newlines), and then using that with `sed` will try to attach all of that to each and every line in the file. It doesn't apply line one of `$var` to line one of the file etc, it applies *all* lines of `$var` to line one of the file, then again to line two, etc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for this explanation - now it is much clearer to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier, using `awk`:

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=, '{print $0, "", "", $4, $6, 0}' file
```

```
https://docs.website.com/12-3/articles/guide-1/article-1.html,,,12-3,guide-1,0
https://docs.website.com/12-2/articles/guide-2/article-5.html,,,12-2,guide-2,0
https://docs.website.com/12-1/articles/guide-3/article-6.html,,,12-1,guide-3,0
```

Comment: Way better than what I was trying to figure out. Thank you.